# Run kubectl on a Virtual Machine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Im trying to get the `kubectl` running on a VM. I followed the steps given [here](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/configure-kubectl.html) and can go thru with the installation. I copied my local kubernetes config (from `/Users/me/.kube/config`) to the VM in the `.kube` directory. However when I run any command such as `kubectl get nodes` it returns `error: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information`

Is there a way I can run `kubectl` on a VM ?

Comment: Where is your cluster hosted? is it GKE? It seems like it is expecting you to do a `gcloud auth login`.

Comment: You could `gcloud auth login` from the VM, but that would use your personal identity for all calls made from that VM. It is safer to create a service account for programmatic access (e.g. if it is ever compromised, you can just revoke the service account's permissions).

Answer (score 1):

To use kubectl to talk to Google Container Engine cluster in a non-Google VM, you can create a user-managed [IAM Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), and use it to authenticate to your cluster:

```
# Set these variables for your project
PROJECT_ID=my-project
SA_NAME=my-new-serviceaccount
SA_EMAIL=$SA_NAME@$PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
KEY_FILE=~/serviceaccount_key.json

# Create a new GCP IAM service account.
gcloud iam service-accounts create $SA_NAME

# Download a json key for that service account.
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create $KEY_FILE --iam-account $SA_EMAIL

# Give that service account the "Container Engine Developer" IAM role for your project.
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID --member serviceAccount:$SA_EMAIL --role roles/container.developer

# Configure Application Default Credentials (what kubectl uses) to use that service account.
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$KEY_FILE
```

And then go ahead and use kubectl as you normally would.

Comment: Where does `~/serviceaccount_key.json` come from? Edit: Found it under `API CONSOLE CREDENTIALS` here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials